# Clear tkinter label contents after set time

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have a label that is updated with status information.  What I would like to do is clear its contents after 10 seconds if the status doesn't change.  For example I set the label to to "step one" then after 10 seconds it gets cleared "".  Now if before the 10 seconds expires I set the label to "Step two" it will update and reset the the 10 second timer.

**EDIT:**
OK, I never could get this to work right.  I made a small app to test that has 3 buttons, two of which just change the text of a label.  What I want to happen is the following.

1. Update the label with the text (Push button 1, or 2)
2. start a 2 second timer. (after 2 seconds clear the label)
3. if button 1 or 2 is pressed before 2 seconds is up update label and reset the timer.
   what I'm seeing is the timer is holding up things.  If I press button 1 the label is updated and the timer starts.  But I can't press either buttons again until the timer is finished

```py
    import tkinter as tk
    
    class Window(tk.Frame):
    
        def __init__(self, master=None):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)        
            self.master = master            
            self.myafter = None
    
           
            # widget can take all window
            self.pack(fill= tk.BOTH, expand=1)
    
            # create button, link it to clickExitButton()
            startButton = tk.Button(self, text="MSG_1", command=self.clickButton1 )        
            startButton.place(x=10,y=10,width=50,height=50)
    
            stopButton = tk.Button(self, text="MSG_2", command=self.clickButton2)        
            stopButton.place(x=100,y=10,width=50,height=50)
    
            exitButton = tk.Button(self, text="EXIT", command=self.clickExitButton)        
            exitButton.place(x=190,y=10,width=50,height=50)
    
            lblstatus =  tk.Label(self, text = "Status:")
            lblstatus.place(x=10, y=150)
            self.lblStatus = tk.Label(self, text = "READY")
            self.lblStatus.place(x=75,y=150)        
            
         
    
        def clickButton1(self): 
            if(self.myafter != None): 
                self.lblStatus.after_cancel(self.myafter)
            app.UpdateMessage("Set message 1")
            
            
    
        def clickButton2(self): 
            if(self.myafter != None): 
                self.lblStatus.after_cancel(self.myafter)              
            app.UpdateMessage("Set message 2")
    
        def ClearStatus(self):
            self.lblStatus["text"] = ""
    
        def UpdateMessage(self,msg= "test"):
            self.lblStatus["text"] = msg
            self.lblStatus.update()
            if(self.myafter == None):
                self.myafter = self.lblStatus.after(2000,self.ClearStatus())
            
    
        def clickExitButton(self):        
            root.quit()
            
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Window(root)
    root.wm_title("Label Clear Test")
    root.geometry("300x200")
    root.mainloop()
```

Thanks
PBSnake

Comment: Do some research on the `after` method.

Answer (score 0):

- Use the `threading` module for this.
- `threading.Timer` is an object that will run parallel to your GUI so it
  won't freeze it.

This code below should do the trick:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading

def myLoop():
    var.set(var.get() + 1) #Increment the value
    threading.Timer(1, myLoop).start()

window = tk.Tk()

var = tk.IntVar()
var.set(1)

button = tk.Button(window, text = 'Threading', command = lambda: threading.Timer(1, myLoop).start()) 
button.pack()
label = tk.Label(window, textvariable = var)
label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I've tried the .after but I'm struggling to get it reset if the label text changes before the time runs out..  also it appears to hang my application

Comment: Post your code so I can work from there please :)

Comment: Tried to do research on the ,after but I'm still struggling.  I updated with code above.